# Can't add a schema to a schema collection

Tags: c++, xml, xsd, msxml, msxml6

**Introduction:**

I am not an expert of C++ nor of MSXML, this is why I am trying to start with things as simple as possible, such as taking some sample code of documentation and try modify some parameters.

Here's the thing, I am using [this example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/ms766421(v=vs.85)) to validate some XML files against XSD schemas.
The code is running good on my computer, and it does what it is supposed to do as long as I keep the code **exactly the same**.

So I'd like to modify this code a little bit just so I can validate my own XML files against my own XSD  schemas.

**What is working :**

So [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/ms766421(v=vs.85)) code works perfectly with [these files](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/ms757054(v=vs.85)). This, at least, proves that I have no problem with my environment or my libraries.

**What I changed :**

As soon as I modify the code to make it validate my own files, it doesn't work anymore.
Here are the few lines I changed :

This :
`CHK_HR(VariantFromString(L"books.xml", varXMLFileName));`

Became this :
`CHK_HR(VariantFromString(L"facturx.xml", varXMLFileName));`

This :
`CHK_HR(VariantFromString(L"books.xsd", varXSDFileName));`

Became this :
`CHK_HR(VariantFromString(L"cii.xsd", varXSDFileName));`

This :
`bstr = SysAllocString(L"urn:books");`

Became this :
`bstr = SysAllocString(L"urn:un:unece:uncefact:data:crossindustry:3:draft");`

Nothing too much spectacular, I am just changing files input.
Also, my files should be pretty clean :

- `cii.xsd` is the - I think - official CII XSD schemas, I found it [there](https://unece.org/trade/uncefact/xml-schemas).
- `facturx.xml` is an example file that should be CII compliant, I found it [there](https://github.com/ConnectingEurope/eInvoicing-EN16931/blob/master/cii/examples/CII_example1.xml)

**What is not working :**

So, from now, with these modified lines, the code is stopping at this line :

```
CHK_HR(pSCache->add(bstr, varXSDObject));
```

When the program runs this line, it stops. Of course, this never occured while I was using the example files.

**What I tried :**

I tried to look at my input files to see if they could have obvious errors that would make the code crash, but I can't find any problem. I also tried with some other files and it still doesn't work.

I tried to put a try/catch(...) block around this line to see what would be the error, but it's not even triggering the catch block, the programs just crashes with no error or no stack trace.

I tried to look at the documentation or other posts in stackoverflow but I can't find anything relevant.

**EDIT :**
I managed to print the error message by changing the macro from this :

```
// Macro that calls a COM method returning HRESULT value.
#define CHK_HR(stmt) do { hr=(stmt); if (FAILED(hr)) goto CleanUp; } while(0)
```

To this :

```
// Macro that calls a COM method returning HRESULT value.
#define CHK_HR(stmt) do { hr=(stmt); if (FAILED(hr)) {std::string message = std::system_category().message(hr);std::cout << message; goto CleanUp;} } while(0)
```

And the error message is :
`Unspecified error`

How am I supposed to know what is the problem...

**What am I asking :**

So, I have a few question, if I can have one answer, it would help a lot :

What can I try to identify where the problem comes from? As I said I am not an expert of C++ so I don't really know the best ways to debug. Variables content are incomprehensible and I can't make it raise an exception or a stacktrace.

Is the problem coming from my code or from my files?

What is the problem?

I'm a little bit desesperate because this shouldn't be so hard to just take sample code and modify it, but it looks like it's harder than expected.

Comment: Does that schema do have `xs:import` or `xs:include` of further schema modules? I think for any external resources to be loaded with MSXML 6 you need to explicitly set a permission `resolveExternals` to true. I can't spell out how to do it with C++ and I am not sure where you need to set it, I would first try with `(*ppDoc)->put_resolveExternals(VARIANT_TRUE);`. If that doesn't work try loading the schema itself into a DOM document of its own where you have set that resolveExternals property to true before loading, then add the schema DOM doc to the collection.

Comment: There were indeed some `xs:include` but after removing it and testing the code again, it changes nothing. I'll keep it in mind tho, it might cause me some troubles later. Thanks for your answer.